# Write to one QProcess with several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have simple programm which must work with several input threads and i want to write simple Qt-programm to test it.
So i start QProcess with this code:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess;
proc->start("D:\\compile\\referee_system\\referee_system");
if(!proc->waitForStarted()) {
    qDebug() << "failed to start process";
    return;
}
```

If i want to send/get data to process in main thread, i can do smth like this:

```
proc->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s), sizeof(DataStruct));
proc->waitForReadyRead();
QByteArray a = proc->readAll();
```

But how can i write to this process with several independent threads?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.
I wrote simple test function:

```
void writeData(QProcess *p) {
    qDebug() << "writing data";
    DataStruct s;
    s.id = qrand()%2;
    s.type = START;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        s.data[i] = qrand()%128;

    p->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s), sizeof(DataStruct));
    p->waitForBytesWritten();
    p->waitForReadyRead();

    QByteArray a = p->readAll();

    qDebug() << a;
}
```

When i call it from main thread, there is no problem, but if i try to use smth like this:

```
QVector<QFuture<void> > vec;

for(int i = 0; i < c_thread_count; ++i) {
    QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::run(writeData, proc);
    vec << f;
}

for(int i = 0; i < c_thread_count; ++i) {
    vec[i].waitForFinished();
}
```

I have an error:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QProcess(0x1549d248), parent's thread is QThread(0x13d13148), current thread is QThread(0x154dbd90)
```

Comment: Send the data from each thread, via signal and slots to the QProcess and write the data. Don't use waitForReadyRead, rather the signal [readyRead](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: This looks like it would rather test your Qt program, not so much the program you run via QProcess, as that won’t see anything of your multiple threads, provided you synchronize the input to stdin on the Qt-side correctly.